# what does this error mean? and how to fix it

Tags: python

```
x = open('Homework.docx','r')
print(x.readline())
x.close()
```

I got this Error whan I ran this code

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 591: character maps to <undefined>
```

then I changed it to:

```
x = open('Homework.docx','rb')
print(x.readline())
x.close()
```

This is what I got:

btw I'm using python shell on windows

```
b'PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x06\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00!\x002\x91oWf\x01\x00\x00\xa5\x05\x00\x00\x13\x00\x08\x02[Content_Types].xml \xa2\x04\x02(\xa0\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xb4\x94\xcbj\xc30\x10E\xf7\x85\xfe\x83\xd1\xb6\xd8J\xba(\xa5\xc4\xc9\xa2\x8fe\x1bh\xfa\x01\x8a4ND\xf5B\xa3\xbc\xfe\xbe\xe381\xa5$14\xc9\xc6 \xcf\xdc{\xcf\x081\x83\xd1\xda\x9al\t\x11\xb5w%\xeb\x17=\x96\x81\x93^i7+\xd9\xd7\xe4-\x7fd\x19&\xe1\x940\xdeA\xc96\x80l4\xbc\xbd\x19L6\x010#\xb5\xc3\x92\xcdS\n'
```

Comment: It's probably a good idea to use a dedicated library to read word documents: https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/documents.html

Answer (score 1):

Encode this in `utf-8`:

```
x = open('Homework.docx', mode="r", encoding="utf8")
```

Comment: When I changed it to x = open('Homework.docx', mode="r", encoding="utf8") , I got this error :    UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x91 in position 15: invalid start byte